# Divide two row values based on label and create a new column to populate the calculated value

Tags: pandas

New to Python and looking for some help.

I would like to divide values in two different rows (part of the same column) and then insert a new column with the calculated value

```
    City              2017-18                     Item
0       Boston              100                       Primary
1       Boston              200                       Secondary
2       Boston              300                       Tertiary
3       Boston              400                       Nat'l average
4       Chicago             500                       Primary
5       Chicago             600                       Secondary
6       Chicago             700                       Tertiary
7       Chicago             800                       Nat'l average
```

On the above Dataframe, I am trying to divide a City's Primary, Secondary and Tertiary values respectively by the Nat'l average for that City. The resultant answer to be populated in a new column part of the same Dataframe. After calculation, the row with the label 'Nat'l average' need to be deleted.

Appreciate your help...

```
         City         2014-15         Item             New_column
0       Boston         100           Primary          100/400
1       Boston         200           Secondary        200/400
2       Boston         300           Tertiary         300/400
3       Chicago        500           Primary          500/800 
4       Chicago        600           Secondary        600/800
5       Chicago        700           Tertiary         700/800
```

Comment: Is `Nat'l average` always last per groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If mean value is always last per groups divide column by `Series` created by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df['new'] = df['2017-18'].div(df.groupby('City')['2017-18'].transform('last'))
```

If not first filter values with `average`s and divide by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)ing Series:

```
s = df[df['Item'] == "Nat'l average"].set_index('City')['2017-18']
df['new'] = df['2017-18'].div(df['City'].map(s))
```

And last filter out rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Item'] != "Nat'l average"]
print (df)
      City  2017-18       Item    new
0   Boston      100    Primary  0.250
1   Boston      200  Secondary  0.500
2   Boston      300   Tertiary  0.750
4  Chicago      500    Primary  0.625
5  Chicago      600  Secondary  0.750
6  Chicago      700   Tertiary  0.875
```

Detail:

```
print (df['City'].map(s))
0    400
1    400
2    400
3    400
4    800
5    800
6    800
7    800
Name: City, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I thought the same as well, but it's not simply mean.